# How to wrap marker labels in matplotlib/networkx

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

I am trying to create a network graph using networkx and matplotlib. I have this code:

```
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, graph_pos, node_size=node_size, 
                       alpha=node_alpha, node_color=node_color)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, graph_pos, width=edge_tickness,
                       alpha=edge_alpha, edge_color=edge_color)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, graph_pos, labels=labels, font_size=node_text_size,
                        font_family=text_font)
plt.show()
```

Which results in the following plot: 
[network plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKouJ.png)

As you can see, some of the marker labels are long and get cut off the edge of the plot. Is there any way to wrap the text of these labels to fit within the plot area?

**Edit:**

The data is a 45x45 matrix from a .csv file that I imported using:

```
network = pd.read_csv('Network.csv')
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(network.values)
graph_pos = nx.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(G, prog='neato')
```

Comment: Can you add your data to this question?

Comment: Added a description - do you need me to copy and paste the csv into the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a hack to get it done, though not sure if this is the best way:

```
for l in labels:
if len(labels[l]) > 55:
    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(list(labels[l])) if x == ' ']
    indices = np.asarray(indices)
    try:
        idx = indices[indices > 55][0]
        newlabel = list(labels[l])
        newlabel.insert(idx, ' \n')
        newlabel = ''.join(newlabel)
        labels[l] = newlabel
    except:
        continue
```